# Descargar y guardar imagen en swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Tengo un servicio web en donde esta una foto y necesito descargarla a mi dispositivo, guardarla y ademas crear una carpeta donde se debe de guardar la imagen desde swift 2.

como puedo lograrlo hacer? como lo hago?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Esto funciona en un Playground:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/beach-images/beach-images-5.jpg")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Es recomendable que no hagas esto en el "main thread" para no bloquear la UI mientras que descarga la imagen.

Para guardar la imagen a disco, la clase `NSData` tiene [métodos writeToFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) para eso.

Comment: pero necesito que cuando este haciendo la descarga muestre un dialog con un mensaje y cuando finalice la descarga desaparezca el dialog.

Comment: Hola @AndresGuillermoCastellanosA. Esta es una buena respuesta. Quizás la parte del diálogo la puedas trabajar tú.

Comment: Los dialogos los tengo el dilema es que no encontrado la manera de hacerlo ya que me pasa de largo y me hace otra cosa mientras descarga la imagen